# How to translate numbers in Ionic angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a calculator application by Ionic framework in my local language. I translated the whole application but till unable to translate numbers to my local language. for example if the results come in the display "344" it must be show to user "३४४". this is for hindi language. and so on like that.